# How does REST know about the service schema?

Tags: rest

How does REST know about the service schema if it doesn't have a WSDL file? By using HTTP methods, the web service operation can be carried out but how does REST know  about the types of data that the web service supports?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Having a WADL file associated with a RESTful service is not mandatory. REST works even without such a description. What I need to know is, how that works even without a schema and service descritpion. And REST is an architecture style, not a protocol.

Comment: REST can work without a WADL, but if the wrong types/data are passed, it will still fail (question upvoted +1).

Comment: Yes, I know that it will receive the HTTP response code to know that. But there should be a schema to let the user know about the data types that the service can accept. What if it's a complex data type?

Comment: all you need is a very good documentation. check this: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen REST is not a protocol REST is an architecture style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST architecture is based (among others) on following elements.

1. An uniform interface
2. Resources and resource identifiers
3. Representations

So in case of the concrete realization of REST in RESTful HTTP the elements are mapped to

1. HTTP methods
2. URIs
3. Content/MIME-type

So the actual data schema is represented in RESTful HTTP by the MIME-type. Therefore the client can process the data without extra knowledge.

Think of a browser, if a browser requests a `.html` file (by using the uniform interface) the HTML parser is triggered to parse the page and if the browser requests `.css` file the CSS parser is triggered.

If you are using certain standardized MIME-Types there is no additional documentation required (unfortunately they don't exists for all use cases). Every client can handle your API without implicit or extra knowledge.

If you want to learn at first hand about REST please take a look at [Representational State Transfer (REST)](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).